# PHP редирект через n секунд для определенных страниц

Tags: php, wordpress, редирект

Как сделать на php редирект через определенное время и только на определенных страницах сайта(сайт на wordpress)

Чтобы страницы выдергивались рандомно из файла .txt

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле всё достаточно просто

```
$sites = file("ссылка_на_текстовый_файл.txt")
```

Эта функция получит все строки текстового файла и поместит их в массив и дальше нам остаётся только добавить проверку. Тут можем обойтись обычным if.

```
$link = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (in_array($link, sites)) {
    sleep(30);
    header('Location:page.html');
}
```

Если сайт есть в списке, то редирект произойдёт через 30 секунд.

Дополняю, отвечая на вопрос в комментарий:
Если нужно перенаправить на рандомный сайт - получаем массив сайтов, на которые нужно перенаправлять (допустим они так же находятся в текстовом файле, соответственно получаем массив способом, аналогичным описанному выше).

Массив назовём "locationTo".
Header будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
header('Location:' . $locationTo[array_rand($locationTo)]);
```

array_rand - возвращает один или несколько (если вторым аргументом указать необходимое количество) случайных ключей из массива

Comment: <?php $sites = file("страница_где_выводится_перенаправление.txt")

$link = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (in_array($link, sites)) {
    sleep(30);
    header('Location:page.html');
}
php>

страницы куда перенаправляет должны тоже дергаться из файла рандомно
Как это осуществить? Вы уж извините но в php я ноль

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Там ответил на ваш вопрос

Comment: Этот вариант может быть проблематичным в виду ограничения на время ответа сервера. Удобнее будет выводить случайный сайт в страницу, а там с помощью Javascript делать переход по нужному промежутку.

Comment: Согласен по поводу ограничения. Ответил на вопрос касательно как это реализуется на PHP. Если конкретно нужно сделать на PHP, то проблему тайм-аута можно решить установкой "max_execution_time". С вашим вариантом я так же полностью согласен

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>


    function redirect()
    {
        window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
    }

    setTimeOut(redirect, 3000)

</script>
```

Редирект на google.com через 3 секунды

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно

Comment: Вам нужен редирект на стороне бекэнда?

Comment: Почему не то, на бекэнде вы должны узнать нужен ли для данной страницы или нет, соответственно решаете ставить этот скрипт или нет

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы скрипт появлялся на заданных страницах(которые нужно взять из файла)
Например на странице 1-5 он появляется и там редиректит, а на страницах 6-10 нет этого скрипта и страница не редиректит пользователя

Comment: Вам нужно скрестить между собой два приведенных ответа: на серверной стороне - читать файл, а на клиентской добавлять js для редиректа